# Why doesn't Lightroom load files after I've changed their camera model metadata using EXIFTOOL?

Tags: troubleshooting, metadata, fujifilm, exiftool

I shoot with Fuji (.RAF). I am currently having issues in changing camera model on Mac.

I tried using the command line

```
exiftool -Model="..." <filename>.raf
```

It says the file was updated, but the file cannot be opened in Lightroom at all. I tried checking the metadata with Adobe Bridge as well but it/s not showing anything. I assume the file itself has become corrupted or something?

I don't know anything about coding as well so this is new to me. I just want to change the camera model. I need it for my old camera profiles.

Comment: Can you explain the "need it for my old camera profiles" part? Why is that relevant to files from your new camera?

Answer (score 6):

You do not ever want to change the make and model of a raw file such as a .RAF (or .NEF/.CR2/3).  Without this data, Lightroom (and other raw file processors) are unable to determine the proper way of rendering the image.

This is covered in [exiftool FAQ #8](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q8).

> The Make and Model tags are used by some image utilities (including
>   ExifTool) to determine the format of the maker note information.
>   Deleting or changing either of these tags may prevent these utilities
>   from recognizing or properly interpreting the maker notes (which, for
>   a RAW image, may mean that the image can no longer be properly
>   rendered).